# Full Outer Join Help Please

Tags: mysql

I am using `MySQL` in my `Crystal Reports`.
I have 2 queries and i need to apply `full outer join` between those two. But as we know `MySQL` won't support for `full outer join`. So i gave `full outer join` by using `left outer join union right outer` between those 2 command objects.

It is working fine.but i have many common columns in both the queries. Take an example there is one column called `Till Number`. There is a case that if `command1.tillnumber` is null then i need to display `command2.tillnumber` but now we are applying full outer join. I mean we have only one query. So it is giving all the data. So how can i get query 1 data if it is not null.

The query for full outer join is below:

```
SELECT q1.pos_no
, q1.pos_name
, q1.start_trans_id
, q1.end_trans_id
, q1.EodDeposit
, q2.net
FROM ( <<<QUERY:1>>> ) AS q1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( <<<QUERY:2>>> ) AS q2
ON q2.pos_no = q1.pos_no
UNION
SELECT q2.pos_no
, q2.pos_name
, q1.start_trans_id
, q1.end_trans_id
, q1.EodDeposit
, q 2. net
FROM ( <<<QUERY:1>>> ) AS q 1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
( <<<QUERY:2>>> ) AS q2
ON q1. pos_no = q2. pos_no
;
```

Please suggest

Comment: TO the second half of the UNION, add `AND q2.pos_no is not null`.

Comment: Probably best to use that as a subselect, but bring back all the possible required columns from each query and then use IFNULL in the outer select to decide whether to pull the columns from the q1 or q2 columns

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way by making the result set as the `table` and further apply your conditions on the columns

```
SELECT q.* FROM (
SELECT q1.pos_no
, q1.pos_name
, q1.start_trans_id
, q1.end_trans_id
, q1.EodDeposit
, q2.net
FROM ( <<<QUERY:1>>> ) AS q1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
( <<<QUERY:2>>> ) AS q2
ON q2.pos_no = q1.pos_no
UNION
SELECT q2.pos_no
, q2.pos_name
, q1.start_trans_id
, q1.end_trans_id
, q1.EodDeposit
, q 2. net
FROM ( <<<QUERY:1>>> ) AS q 1
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
( <<<QUERY:2>>> ) AS q2
ON q1. pos_no = q2. pos_no
) q WHERE q.pos_no !="" AND q.start_trans_id !="" // same way add the conditions
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Using IFNULL

```
SELECT IFNULL(q1_pos_no, q2_pos_no)
, IFNULL(q1_pos_name, q2_pos_name)
, IFNULL(q1_start_trans_id, q2_start_trans_id)
, IFNULL(q1_end_trans_id, q2_end_trans_id)
, IFNULL(q1_EodDeposit, q2_EodDeposit)
, IFNULL(q1_net, q2_net)
FROM 
(
    SELECT q1.pos_no AS q1_pos_no
    , q1.pos_name AS q1_pos_name
    , q1.start_trans_id AS q1_start_trans_id
    , q1.end_trans_id AS q1_end_trans_id
    , q1.EodDeposit AS q1_EodDeposit
    , q1.net AS q1_net,
    , q2.pos_no AS q2_pos_no
    , q2.pos_name AS q2_pos_name
    , q2.start_trans_id AS q2_start_trans_id
    , q2.end_trans_id AS q2_end_trans_id
    , q2.EodDeposit AS q2_EodDeposit
    , q2.net AS q2_net
    FROM ( <<<QUERY:1>>> ) AS q1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ( <<<QUERY:2>>> ) AS q2
    ON q2.pos_no = q1.pos_no
    UNION
    SELECT q1.pos_no AS q1_pos_no
    , q1.pos_name AS q1_pos_name
    , q1.start_trans_id AS q1_start_trans_id
    , q1.end_trans_id AS q1_end_trans_id
    , q1.EodDeposit AS q1_EodDeposit
    , q1.net AS q1_net,
    , q2.pos_no AS q2_pos_no
    , q2.pos_name AS q2_pos_name
    , q2.start_trans_id AS q2_start_trans_id
    , q2.end_trans_id AS q2_end_trans_id
    , q2.EodDeposit AS q2_EodDeposit
    , q2.net AS q2_net
    FROM ( <<<QUERY:1>>> ) AS q 1
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    ( <<<QUERY:2>>> ) AS q2
    ON q1. pos_no = q2. pos_no
) Sub1
;
```

Comment: Hi Kichstart, can you please tell what is sub1 at end of query and i tried the same but i am getting the error like below.Please help                          SELECT IFNULL(q1.pos_no, q2.pos_no) , IFNULL(q1.pos_name, q2.pos_name) , IFNULL(q1.start_trans_id, q2.start_trans_id) , IFNULL(q...
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'q1.pos_no' in 'field list'

Comment: Sub1 is an alias, and if you are selecting from a subselect an alias is compulsory for the subselect. The error is a typo when giving an alias name to a column in one of the unioned queries.